# How to make a "page-option" in WordPress

Tags: php, widgets

I had made a WordPress website with my own theme.
I have a navigation menu on the top of my website with dropdowns.

Then you click on a page in this menu, I want you to navigate to a page, where there is a specific widget with a navigation...

But, on another dropdown page I want another widget.

So, my question is: "How can I make an "option" to choose the right widget to a specific page?".

I hope someone can help! - thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define a specific page template for the specific widget then you can select template page as on your navigation menu.

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: page one
*/
get_header();
?>

    <div class="main-wrap ">
        <?php
            if (is_active_sidebar( "widgetName" )) {
                dynamic_sidebar( "widgetName" );
            }
        ?>
    </div> 

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```